# gcloud: command not found when starting Cloud SQL Auth proxy with docker and container optimised OS

Tags: mysql, docker, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set-up a Cloud SQL Auth proxy with a Cloud SQL for MySQL instance.

I'm following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#cloud-sql-auth-proxy-docker-image_1) but without success.

so I'm creating a new VM instance. Once it has been created I'm running the following command in the cloud shell

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west2-c" "nameinstance"  --tunnel-through-iap --project "my_project"
```

From what I understand this allow me to connect to my instance. Then I'm running the following command:

```
docker pull gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.19.1
```

all good. then I'm kind of lost as when entering `gcloud sql instances describe Cloud_SQL_instance_name` I got the following error gcloud: command not found

and when entering `docker run -d \\ -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 \\ gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.19.1 /cloud_sql_proxy \\ -instances=sql_connection_name=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306` I have the following error `docker: invalid reference format.`

Ultimately, and if I'm right, I should be able to execute successfully the following command `mysql -u USERNAME -p --host 127.0.0.1`

Comment: 1) Did you copy and paste an example and forget that `\\` are line continuation marks? 2) To install the SDK (gcloud): https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container Optimized OS (or COS) target is simple: run containers. That's all. All the other capacity of linux have been deactivated, to keep the kernel small, to reduce the attack surface, and to limit the point of failure (with third party binaries, like gcloud).

Thus, run container with docker (or docker-containerd).

```
# interactive mode
docker run -ti  google/cloud-sdk:latest gcloud version

# Script mode
docker run --entrypoint gcloud google/cloud-sdk:latest version
```

It works as is in startup script. If you log into the VM and want to run these commands, add a `sudo` before to have the permission to run the binaries.

---

So, you will be able to run Cloud SQL proxy in a container, Gcloud in a container, and also MySQL client in a container. Forget the fact to run something without container (and `docker run` command). And think also to redirect the port correct when you run your containers.